# Play framework, SQLTimeoutException

Tags: mysql, playframework

In play framework my every first (after compilation) request  ends with `SQLTimeoutException after 1001 ms`
Text of error:

```
[error] application - 

! @72p3a11me - Internal server error, for (GET) [/read] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1001ms of waiting for a connection.]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1001ms of waiting for a connection.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93)
    at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:12)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:415)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:414)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:297)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:407)
    at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:33)
    at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
```

Controller action:

```
def readEquipment = Action.async { implicit request =>
    equipmentService.read map { eq => Ok(Json.toJson(eq)) }
  }
```

DAO method:

```
override def read(): Future[Seq[Equipment]] =
    db.run(equipment.result)
```

It seems the problem is with lazy initialization which starts only after first request to database. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error is pretty generic, are you sure your db credentials are correct?

Comment: @nmat, the exception is thrown only on first request, but all subsequent requests are successful. Adding th line `slick.dbs.default.db.properties.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/data"` probably solved the problem ("probably" because I don't know how). But first request still takes nearly 10 seconds.